# jquery optimize ,repeated use of this

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the same variables for mouseover and mouseout,is there any way to shorten this?

```js
$('#service_tab li').on('mouseover', function() {

  var $a = $(this).find("a"),
    dt = $a.attr("href");
  $(dt).addClass('tabv');
  $("#tabs-1").addClass('tabh');

});

$('#service_tab li').on('mouseout', function() {
  var $a = $(this).find("a"),
    dt = $a.attr("href");
  $(dt).removeClass('tabv');
  $("#tabs-1").removeClass('tabh');
});
```

Comment: you most likely want mouseenter and mouseleave, not over - out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [event.type](https://api.jquery.com/event.type/).

```
$('#service_tab li').on('mouseover mouseout', function (e) {
    var $a = $(this).find("a"),
    dt = $a.attr("href");
    if (e.type == 'mouseover') {
        $(dt).addClass('tabv');
        $("#tabs-1").addClass('tabh'); 
    } else {
        $(dt).removeClass('tabv');
        $("#tabs-1").removeClass('tabh');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use just one `function` instead of repeat your code.
See the example below.

```
$('#service_tab li').on('mouseover', function() {
  myFunction('mouseover');
});

$('#service_tab li').on('mouseout', function() {
  myFunction('mouseout');
});

function myFunction(value){
  var $a = $(this).find("a"),
  dt = $a.attr("href");

  if(value == 'mouseout'){
    $(dt).removeClass('tabv');
    $("#tabs-1").removeClass('tabh');
  }else{
    $(dt).addClass('tabv');
    $("#tabs-1").addClass('tabh');
  }
}
```

Or you can use a `switch`

```
$('#service_tab li').on('mouseover', function() {
  myFunction('mouseover');
});

$('#service_tab li').on('mouseout', function() {
  myFunction('mouseout');
});

function myFunction(value){
  var $a = $(this).find("a"),
  dt = $a.attr("href");

  switch(value){
    case 'mouseout' : 
      $(dt).removeClass('tabv');
      $("#tabs-1").removeClass('tabh');
      break;
    case 'mouseover': 
      $(dt).addClass('tabv');
      $("#tabs-1").addClass('tabh');
      break;
   }
}
```

Just like **Drow** said (thanks), you can also use [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) method of jquery.

> toggleClass : Add or remove one or more classes from each element in the set of matched elements.

```
$('#service_tab li').hover(function() {
  var $a = $(this).find("a"),
  dt = $a.attr("href");
  $(dt).toggleClass('tabv');
  $("#tabs-1").toggleClass('tabh');
})
```

Comment: Or, since he is only toggling classes, the .hover function and .toggleClasss function can be used: https://codepen.io/Droow/pen/EbpZbV?